# Issues adding and finding data in 2d python array

Tags: python

I'm new to python so I suspect I'm not getting the difference between an array and a list, for starters. Not sure if I should be using numpy.

The piece of code I'm having trouble with wants to create a 2d array. The logic flow I want to achieve works like this:

1. Loop through a list of MAC addresses provided by the network interface
2. Add unique MAC addresses to the first column of my array, one at a time
3. During loop iterations check if a MAC address has been previously added to the first column.
4. If the MAC doesn't exist, put an integer (counting) value of 0 in the 2nd column alongside the MAC.
5. Alternatively if the MAC exists in the first column it wants to retrieve the current 'counting' value from the 2nd column and assign it to a variable. The counting value increments elsewhere.

Here's the broken code:

```
mcloc[[]] #define array

if pkt.addr2 not in mcloc[[]] :
    mcloc.append[pkt.addr2, 0]  
    #add MAC address and set a 0 counter value  
elif
    cntr = mcloc[pkt.addr2,[]]  
    #MAC found, now assign counter var from 2nd column
```

Comment: So what you're saying is, you want to count how many times each MAC address occurs in the list of MAC addresses?

Comment: That seems hard. Have you thought about a dictionary of keys = MACs (guarantees uniqueness) and the value = frequency? Or use the counter type: `>>> from collections import Counter
>>> addresses = ['A','B','C','D','B','C']
>>> Counter(addresses).most_common()
[('B', 2), ('C', 2), ('A', 1),('D',1)]`

Comment: Can you show an example input and output?

Comment: I don't want to count how many times each MAC occurs. The 'counter' value I describe relates to an arbitrary action concerning the MAC address somewhere else in the code. I just need to know if 1. does the mac already exist, if not add it, if it does exist tell me what the current counter value is

Answer (score 2):

Use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

mac_addresses = Counter(list_of_mac_addresses)

# mac_addresses is now a dict-like object, with MAC addresses
# as keys and number of occurrences as values
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems hard. Have you thought about a dictionary of keys = MACs (guarantees uniqueness) and the value = frequency? Or use Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
addresses = ['A','B','C','D','B','C']
Counter(addresses).most_common()
[('B', 2), ('C', 2), ('A', 1),('D',1)]`
```

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, the counter variable I referred to is not to count the mac addresses in my list. This counter variable I referrenced is incremented in different actions (associated with the mac) throughout the code. I don't need to know how many times a MAC has appeared in the list, just if it is there or not (and if it is get the counter value assoicated with it)